# azure webjobs - 'It is not possible for an entity that requires sessions to create a non-sessionful message receiver

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-servicebus-queues

I am trying to trigger azure webjob using azure service bus queue which is FIFO. but following error is occured. is there way to fix it ?

> It is not possible for an entity that requires sessions to create a
>   non-sessionful message receiver.
>   TrackingId:af15f75d-3d5f-423e-92c5-e22b222d25e6_G9_B1,
>   SystemTracker:testsbqueue:Queue:testsbqueuexxx

```
static void Main()
{
    var serviceBusConfi = new ServiceBusConfiguration
    {
        ConnectionString= "Endpoint="",

     };
    var config = new JobHostConfiguration();

    if (config.IsDevelopment)
    {
        config.UseDevelopmentSettings();
    }
    config.UseServiceBus(serviceBusConfi);
    ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = Int32.MaxValue;
    var host = new JobHost(config);
    // The following code ensures that the WebJob will be running continuously
    host.RunAndBlock();
}
```

> Function.cs

```
public class Functions
    {
        // This function will get triggered/executed when a new message is written 
        // on an Azure Queue called queue.
        public static void ProcessQueueMessage([ServiceBusTrigger("testsbqueuexxx") ] string message, TextWriter log)
        {
            log.WriteLine($"[WebJobNotificationProcessor-]-{message}");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can refer to this post. `https://medium.com/@samuelhutama/net-core-azure-service-bus-send-and-receive-message-in-session-enabled-subscription-3f8ffecc47de`

Comment: Try set sessionsEnable to true `public static void ProcessQueueMessage([ServiceBusTrigger(queueName:"testsbqueuexxx", Connection = "", IsSessionsEnabled = true)]`. Or `useSessions` prior to function app v3.1